# To find a subgroup of order $6$ in $U(450)$

Tags: group-theory

Find a subgroup of order $6$ in $U(450)$

I tried expressing it as an external direct product of cyclic groups of the form $Z_{n}$ but since the answer is given as $U_{50}(450)$, I figured it was the wrong approach.But I didn't understand how they arrived at this solution.
I know that $$U_{50}(450)=U_{50}(50.9)\thickapprox U(9)$$
I'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|U(450)|=\phi(450)=120$, the group $U(450)$ has an element $x$ of order $2$, and an element $y$ of order $3$, by Cauchy's Theorem. Hence $H:=\langle xy\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $6$.

For another solution see this duplicate question (replacing $700$ by $450$):

[To Find a subgroup of order $6$ in $U(700).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759288/to-find-a-subgroup-of-order-6-in-u700?rq=1)

Comment: Neat!!...... +1

Comment: I checked out that question but couldn't get the logic before

Comment: Well, yes; the comment of Derek Holt is helpful there:)

Comment: How did you know its a cyclic group?

Comment: I meant $U(450)$

Comment: Who says that this group is cyclic?

Comment: Sorry..it's nothing.I got confused a little before

Comment: @Pigamma, the subgroup constructed by "Dietrich", has order 6. So it is either isomorphic to $Z_6$ or to $S_3$ . But given group is abelian, so it can't have non-abelian subgroups, so it must be isomorphic to $Z_6$ and hence subgroup $H$ must be cyclic.  :-)